# ¿puedo usar este programa con framework 4.5.2 en otra pc con W7?

Tags: c#

Lo que sucede es que necesito crear un programa para un hotel, y como soy nuevo en la programación para aplicaciones de escritorio, comencé mi proyecto y no elegí un framework sinó que dejé el que el visual studio 2017 me ponía arriba, estoy programando en mi maquina windows 7 X64 y la maquina en la que necesito instalar cuando termine es una windows 7 x32, ¿hay algun problema con el framework que estoy usando? ¿como solucionarlo si hay un error? dejo pantallazo del S.O del cliente. [![introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí][1]][1]

Aqui va la imagen del framework, es decir, supongo que a la hora de crear mi proyecto salía igual, yo no le cambié nada, acá solo estoy haciendo como si fuese a crear un proyecto nuevo para mirar simplemente el framework de elige por defecto el VS.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

¿tendré problemas si estoy programando en W7 de 64  pero lo hago
para un Windows 7 de 32 ? 
A la hora de probarlo en mi pc, por ejemplo.

No sé, ayudenme, necesito consejos.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Windows 7 permite instalar hasta .Net Framework 4.7x, asi que no tendrás problema por el Framework. Donde podrías tener problema es con Windows XP o Windows Server 2003, que solo soportan hasta .Net Framework 4.0

En cuanto a la arquitectura, no debes tener problema, deja la opción por default y el ejecutable funcionará tanto en W7 32 bits como 64 bits.

Por cierto, yo quitaría la captura que pusiste, estás mostrando datos como la clave de registro de Windows, y el nombre de tu euipo.

Comment: Gracias, podrías darme si eres tan amable el paso a paso para poner la arquitectura por default. 
¿Sabes como hacer un ejecutable con SQLite ? es que tengo mi programa, pero no sé como hacer el ejecutable añadiendo la base, de hecho me guié viendo este tutorial sobre como implementar SQLite a un programa. 
(abajo link) ¿podrias ayudarme? es importante.
.
.
.
https://danielggarcia.wordpress.com/2013/12/21/bases-de-datos-portables-utilizando-sqlite-en-una-aplicacion-net/#more-870

Comment: Para cambiar la arquitectura de tu proyecto solo dale botón derecho en el proyecto (en la ventana donde te salen los archivos .cs) y seleccionas propiedades, luego te vas a la pestaña de compilar (o build) y cambias la opción de destino (o platform target) a "any cpu".